# How to insert sql query results in one single line in csv from php?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, csv

The following code output the sql query result into a csv file :

**CODE**

```
<?php
// Report all errors except E_NOTICE   
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE); 

//connection file
include("connection.php");  

$query      = 'SELECT resting_blood_sugar,serum_cholesterol,thalach,oldpeak,result,date from hd_test WHERE patient_id = 2';         
$output = fopen('N:\oldpatientgraph.csv', 'w');
$result = mysqli_query($link,$query);

// loop over the rows, outputting them
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) fputcsv($output, $row);

?>
```

**OUTPUT**

The csv file contains output in following format :

1,1,1,1,1,11-1-2015 #line1

2,3,1,4,2,1-1-2000  #line2

Whereas i want to output the result in one line as follows :

1,1,1,1,1,11-1-2015,2,3,1,4,2,1-1-2000 #line1

Anyone here who knows how to do this ??

Comment: `$out = []; while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) $out = array_merge($out,array_values($row));; fputcsv($output, $out);`

Comment: It Worked @splash58. 
Thanks a lot for the help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just concancenate the row, like below :

```
// loop over the rows, outputting them
$arr1 = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
   $arr1 = array_merge($arr1,array_values($row));
}
fputcsv($output,$arr1);
```

Comment: And you concatenate an array onto a string?

Comment: Yes, This will not work coz fputcsv() wants the second parameter to be an array and not string..

Thanks for the help.

Comment: $out = []; while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) $out = array_merge($out,array_values($row));; fputcsv($output, $out);

This works!

Comment: Your way of merging the array is correct. But fputcsv() doesnot accept the second parameter $things which is string..!

**Have a look at this :**

$out = []; while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) $out = array_merge($out,array_values($row));; fputcsv($output, $out); **This works!**

Comment: sorry, i just think if fputcsv() accept a string, lesson-learned @Neha.

Comment: No problem. Thanks a lot for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

**You can try this**

```
$output = fopen('N:\oldpatientgraph.csv', 'w');
$csvString = '';
$index = 0;
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
  if ($key) {
    $csvString.=',';
  }
  $csvString .= implode(',',array_values($row)); #Array values to string
  $index = 1;
}

fwrite($output, $csvString); #Write string to file
fclose($output);
```

> **Note :** Above code will give you all data in 1 line.

Comment: The data is coming in onle line, but each row of the query result is not separated by comma. Moreover, it doesnot write into the csv file.

Comment: For writing issue, check the proper file `path/permissions` of `'N:\oldpatientgraph.csv'`. Can you give post the `var_dump($row)` data to your Question? @Neha

Comment: There is no issue with writing in the file.. coz it works well with the fputcsv() function.

Comment: Ahh! Okay! (y) @Neha

Comment: Anyway, Thanks for the help :)
@Sumon